# ListView Update Single Item

Tags: android

I would like to update a single listview item and it works fine until I scroll down to items that are not visible and seems that there is an item (which was not visisble) getting updated as well (I see this when I scroll down)

My code:

```
listViewIndex = position;

View v_lv_item = lv.getChildAt(listViewIndex - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
if(v_lv_item  == null)
return;
```

Each listview item has a button that updates a view on that listview row:

```
ibCheckbox = v_lv_item.findViewById(R.id.ibCheckbox);
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        ibCheckbox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_fill);
        lv_custom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
   });
```

[image]

The image above describes the issue, when i update listview item in position 0, the item in position 5 (not visible until i scroll) also updates (it should not) and if i do the same for pos 1 then pos 6 is also updated and so on and so on even vice-versa, eg: when i update pos 7 and scroll up pos 2 will be updated as well, how can I prevent this and only have the listview update the item that i click on (and not update the listview item which is not visible until scroll)?

Comment: Use the notifyItemChanged(int position);

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this article of handling checkboxes. There are 3 methods given. This should solve your problem:

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022